# Start Menu sorting function: what is this header type? (Refer to screenshot)

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

[image]

I realized just today that I don't think I've ever seen it being available for me to select before.  When would this be used?  (It somewhat resembles a web browser icon?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s the “Other” category:

[image]

It contains broken applications (like in this example) and anything that doesn’t really start with a letter or digit.